# I am not able to send emails from C# code from godaddy VPS hosting

Tags: c#, email

I am not able to send emails from my C# code via Godaddy VPS hosting.

I am getting the following error:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net' at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection

My C# code is:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmailId));
msg.From = new MailAddress(fromEmailId);
msg.Subject = subject;
msg.Body = message;
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 25;
client.Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
```

Please help.

Comment: I think you have your answer in the error message. Its nothing to do with C# or .net; the SMTP server cannot be found. You need to contact GoDaddy to find the correct SMTP server address.

Comment: As I have managed VPS, they are saying I need to manage everything. But on there forums, it is mentioned to use this smtp only

Comment: I've only ever seen an smtp server addressed as "smtp.hostname". Try just putting "smtp." on the front of the address you've been given.

Comment: Are you sure that your SMTP relay is turned on? You should be able to check it in your GoDaddy account or contacting support. The code I use here is almost the same. The only difference is that I declare the host and port in Web.config file, but that shouldn't give you this error.

Comment: @Forlani  I tried with web config as well.. But got the same error. I am using plesk.  not sure which part I am missing and everywhere same code is mentioned as a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your code

```
client.EnableSsl = false;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and its working now.

If you are using Godaddy Windows VPS and want to send email notifications from your website below code needs to be used:

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmailId));
msg.From = new MailAddress("email@domain.com");
msg.Subject = subject;
msg.Body = message;
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@domain.com", "password"); 
client.Port = 25;
client.Host = "localhost";

Also, you need to create the same email on your windows VPS.